# FSNotify add watch directories while running

Tags: file, go, watch, inotify

I don't really know how to formulate the question, but here it is.

I'm using fsnotify to watch some directories for changes and when a file changes, I sync the change to another directory. But I want to add newly created directories to the watch too and it's not really working.

Here's my code:

```
func Watcher() {
    watcher, err := fsnotify.NewWatcher()
    defer watcher.Close()

    done := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case event := <-watcher.Events:

                    if file.Mode().IsDir() {
                    err = os.Mkdir(dest, 0755)
                    err = watcher.Add(dest)

            }
        case err := <-watcher.Errors:
            log.Println("error:", err)
        }
    }
    }()

    dirs, err := readLines("dirs")
    for _, el := range dirs {
        err = watcher.Add(el)
    }
    check(err)
    <-done
}
```

The function is much longer, but I've deleted the non-important parts. Everything works, except the `err = watcher.Add(dest)`.

How can I make it watch more directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was working just fine, but I got some variables wrong. Should have been `watcher.Add(event.Name)` instead of `watcher.Add(dest)`.